# Can Location Modules Geo Code on node save?

Tags: 7, location, google-maps

When I save a node that has a Location associated to it, it does not add the Longitude and Latitude values.  When I run the Autofill empty locations path: admin/config/services/la  it fills in all my nodes that have blank Latitude and Longitude values.

Is this normal?  I wish the Longitude and Latitude values get entered as soon as I save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I have to set a Service for each country I want to use in the Geo Coding Settings: admin/config/content/location/geocoding